# Vaadin GUI Select selectList - setStyle/color of selected item

Tags: java, selection, vaadin

Hi,
I use Select list in vaadin. How can I change the color of selected item on list ?

Comment: Which Vaadin component do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct way of doing it. I've used a [Table](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html) + [CellStyleGenerator](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.css) to simulate a complex list with multiple colours, but I think than you could use [css](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.css.html) and alter the [default style for the selected item](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.selecting.html) (scroll to 5.15.3 ListSelect) if you struggle a bit.